# Simplify piecewise items to fewer

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Is there any special simplification function for this case?

In the following case, first 2 items of piecewise function can be merged.

```
FullSimplify[Piecewise[{{1 + 2 B, B <= e}, {3 + 2 e, B == 1 + e}}], Element[B,Integers] && Element[e,Integers]]
```

The idea is `B <= e && B == 1 + e` can be simplified to `B <= 1 + e`, both with result `1 + 2 B`.

Comment: How do you want `B - e <= 0`  and `B - e == 1` to merge?

Comment: @Daniel Huber `B - e <= 1`, because in that case, both lead to the same result.

Comment: B - e <= 1 is less restrictive than B - e <= 0 and B - e == 1

Comment: so, `a` for `a<0` and `a` for `a>=0` cannot be merged to just `a`? As a human I can do this simplification. Why not a program like Mathematica?